# Como emular um aplicativo para iOS no Windows com PhoneGap?

Tags: windows, apache-cordova, app

Ultimamente estou a desenvolver aplicativos no Windows 8 usando o Framework PhoneGap. Porém, quero saber, como posso emular o aplicativo para iOS no meu sistema operacional Windows?

Existe a possibilidade de fazer isso sem precisar usar o Hackintosh?

Answer (score 2):

Infelizmente não é possível executar aplicação iOS no windows com o Cordova.

Porém, existe uma alternativa interessante, que também é Cordova-Based, que é o [Steroids](http://www.appgyver.com/steroids), da [AppGyver](http://www.appgyver.com/). Que permite o build e execução de aplicações em múltiplos devices através de streaming.

O steroids tem um CLI bem rico que permite scaffolding, testes, etc. O melhor de tudo é o comando ***steroids connect***, que inicia um webserver local, com um código QR que pode ser lido pelo device através do AppGyver Scanner, que por sua vez transfere a aplicação e você  pode ver o resultado final em mãos.

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se já encontrou uma solução para o que estava perguntando, mas hoje consegui emular em tempo real uma criação Jquery Mobile, criada no Windows, diretamente no meu iPhone. A solução foi utilizar o app Phonegap developer. Encontrei esta dica no seguinte endereço:

http://pt.slideshare.net/FonsoFernandes/phonegap-autorefresh-app-direto-no-celular

Achei incrível a velocidade de atualização no iPhone, praticamente instantânea!

Comment: Acho que não é bem isso que ele quer, ele quer um emulador de iOS para Windows.